# How can I hide .un~ files when I run "ls" in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, ls

Is there any option I can pass to ls to hide .un~ files from the output?

I want to be able to see *all* files (e.g. dotfiles) except .un~ files, so I need to run `ls -A` and add something to hide the .un~ files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew *does* provide GNU `ls` through the `coreutils` package.

```
brew install coreutils
```

Then, you could `alias` your system `ls` to GNU `ls`, which Homebrew installs as `gls` instead in order to prevent overriding the usage of system binaries:

```
alias ls='/usr/local/bin/gls'
```

Alternatively, as outlined in `brew info coreutils`:

> If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you
>   can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
>
> ```
> PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
> ```

Proceed with using GNU `ls` options if they better suit your needs, e.g.

```
ls -B
```

or similarly:

```
alias ls='/usr/local/bin/gls --hide=*~'
```

Answer (score -2):

ls -B

Hides backups, files ending in ~

Comment: Doesn't work on my MacBook Pro, I am still seeing the .un~ files

Comment: -1, this only applies to GNU `ls`, the `-B` option has a totally different meaning in OS X (or BSD `ls` for that matter).

Comment: @gws The question is if you would be fine with changing `ls`, i.e. compiling and aliasing to GNU ls, thus deviating from what comes with OS X.

Comment: @slhck I guess so, I typically use homebrew but it doesn't provide a GNU ls